# Artin Algebra 4.1.5

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, self-learning

This question comes from the 1st edition and was asked in the Harvard lecture videos on Abstract Algebra.

> Let $A$ be a $k\times m$ matrix and let $B$ be an $n\times p$ matrix. Prove that the rule $M\leadsto AMB$ defines a linear transformation from the space $F^{m\times n}$ of $m\times n$ matrices to the space $F^{k\times p}$

I am unsure of what is being asked here, as I feel it follows directly from the definitions. The domain of the rule must be $F^{m\times n}$; otherwise, the product $AMB$ is not defined. The codomain is the space of matrices with shape given by the "outer indices" of the matrices in the product. In this case, $k\times p$.

Is this answer correct? What am I missing here to make this argument formal, if it is at all valid?

Comment: Just because the domain and codomain of the function are right that doesn’t mean that it’s linear.

Comment: @Randall Absolutely! I should also mention that the product of linear matrices is linear, and associative so that $AMB=(AM)B=A(MB)$ is a linear transformation. Is that enough, though?

Comment: That isn’t the definition of linear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're being asked to show that the definition of linearity applies to this map. Denote $f :M \mapsto AMB$. I'll use the definition that a map $f$ is linear if for vectors $x_1,x_2$ and scalars $k_1,k_2$, we have $f(k_1x_1 + k_2x_2) = k_1f(x_1) + k_2f(x_2)$; there are several equivalent versions of this definition. For matrices $M_1,M_2$ and scalars $k_1,k_2$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
f(k_1M_1 + k_2M_2) &= A(k_1M_1 + k_2M_2)B
\\ & = (k_1AM_1 + k_2 AM_2)B 
\\ & = k_1 (AM_1B) + k_2 (AM_2B) = k_1 f(M_1) + k_2 f(M_2).
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $f$ is a linear map.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Quick question, isn't the linearity of the rule implied directly from the fact that matrix multiplications are linear maps?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the statement "matrix multiplications are linear maps"?

Comment: Typically, the statement refers the the fact that every linear map over $\Bbb F^m$ can be written in the form $x \mapsto Mx$. This does not, in and of itself, tell you that the maps $M \mapsto AM$ and $M \mapsto MB$ are linear over $\Bbb F^{m \times n}$. That said, it is indeed the case that these maps are linear, and the linearity of your map is a consequence of this fact.